# Unclear about modulus function c language

Tags: c

Here is a C language function, which I am having a little trouble understanding. I need to show what values of `r` come out when I input values of 6 or 10 or 13 into the function:

```
int factor(int val){
int r=val-1;

while(val%r){
r--;

}
return r;

}
```

I'm not sure if I misunderstood the question but wouldn't the remainder always be true? Since `0 = false` and the while statement never reaches 0 because `r` is always smaller than `val` and not equal to it, and each time `r` decreases the remainder just gets bigger?

Edit: Just realized i forgot to account that 6%3 = 0! thanks for the help people who helped!

Comment: Looks like a prime test to me (albeit a bad one). Will return 1 for prime numbers and the largest factor otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test for yourself: `4 % 2`.
The result should be `0` as the `%` operator returns the remainder of a division.

`while(x % y) {}` translates in this context to something like: as long as `x` is not dividable by `y`, do something, whereby 'do something' is decrease `y` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the function returns the largest factor of the number input to the method.

It translates to "while there is a remainder from division (`r` is NOT a factor of `val`), decrease r by 1 and check again. Once the clean factor is found (`val % r is 0`), return the factor (`r`).

Here's a JavaScript port with sample output:

http://jsfiddle.net/43HxX/2/

I rewrote it in JS and you can uncomment the `alert(...)` line to see the output for 6, 10, and 13